# Homology and triangulation of open surfaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For example I have an open disk, or an open annulus.

1. How do I triangulate open surfaces to find their (simplicial) Homology?

Well, I know that open disk and closed disk are both homotopic to a point (contractible) so their homology are the same, which is trivial except for $p=0$ which is $\mathbb{Z}$. By intuition I think open and closed annulus also have the same homology.

2. Is it true generally?

Comment: Annulus is homotopic to a circle which has trivial zero homology and $\mathbb{Z}$ for it's first homology.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood, I know that. I am just asking more technical thing. How do I triangulate open surfaces, and if I have a closed surface $X$ whether $H_*(X)=H*(Int(X))$?